# How do I get the value from a node using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a>
    <a>
      <b>some data</b>
      <c>other data</c>
    </a>
    <a>
      <b>some data</b>
      <c>other data</c>
    </a>
  </a>
</aBase>
```

I want to get all data from `<b>` nodes using LINQ to XML.
I have tried something like this:

```
var query = from c in xmlData.Descendants("b")
            select c.Value;
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?
Also, what is the difference between Descendents, Elements and Nodes?

Comment: What is "not working" about it?  Your query will already return all `<b>` values as strings.  Isn't that what you wanted?  There aren't any namespaces in play to complicate things.

Comment: It's return me all <b> and all <c>, because probably it's checking first (outer) <a> node. whyleee solution's appropiate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this query to get all information from inner `a` nodes:

```
var query = from e in doc.Root.Elements( "a" ).Elements( "a" )
            select new { B = e.Element( "b" ).Value, C = e.Element( "c" ).Value };
```

But this is just a query. To execute it and work with results write this code:

```
foreach ( var e in query )
{
    // Do something with results... For example, write to console:
    Console.WriteLine( "B: " + e.B + ", C: " + e.C );
}
```

**Node** is the one element of the XML tree. `aBase` element, all the `a`, `b` and `c` elements - the nodes of the XML document.

**Elements** is just the child elements of selected node (in one level of hierarchy). For example for the `aBase` node the only child element is the outer `a` element, not the inner `a`, `b` or `c` element.

**Descendants** is all the elements that are child or descendants to the current node (in all levels of hierarchy). All elements are the descendants to the `aBase` element because it is the main element of the document.

Comment: `doc.Descendants("a").Descendants("a")` will have duplicate references, as the first `Descendants("a")` will already include EVERY a element in the document.

Comment: No, the second `.Descendants( "a" )` will select the childs of the outer `a` elements.

Comment: true, but so does the first one. I think if you want to only get the children of the outer A elements `Root.Elements("a").Elements("a")` is the better approach. Then again, having A elements in other A elements seems an unlikely situation in the first place.

Comment: Ok, so I must go step by step through all level, right? But if 'descendents' means all childs, so why it can't find desired node?

Comment: Yes. Solution with Root.Elements("a").Elements("a") works too

Comment: There are an extension methods `Descendants()` and `Elements()` to the `IEnumerable<XElement>`. So it's will be all right.

Comment: @Whyleee because you have elements named A inside Elements named A. So you cannot directly go to the elements that you are after because they are indistinguishable from their parent elements which you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

`xmlData.Descendants("b")` will give you a collection of XElements with XName equal to "b". You can then iteration over this collection to get every value:

```
var data = xmlData.Descendants("b");
foreach (XElement b in data)
{
 string value = b.Value;
 // do something with value here
}
```

`Descendants` will give you any Element that is a descendant, not only the direct children, but also the children of them. So in your case `xmlData.Root.Descendants("b")` will return a collection over every B element in the file. `Elements` does the same thing but only for direct descendants and `Nodes` does the same thing but includes comments and textNodes.

Comment: Not exactly. This method returns me all value of outer "a"-node. So it's sth like: "some dataother data some dataother data"

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
var query = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "a").Elements(ns + "a").Elements().Select(el => el.Value);
```

Please note that you don't even need neither the `Descendants` method nor iteration through descendants. `Elements` without parameters returns direct descendants, and `Select` method extracts values of descendants. And don't forget about xml namespace or elements names could not be found. Without namespace you're trying to extract different elements, not the elements in your xml.

As for difference between different methods:

1. `Nodes()` returns `IEnumerable<XNode>`
2. `Elements()` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>`
3. `Descendants()` returns all descendant elements (including all deeply nested elements in opposite to `Nodes` and `Elements` return only 1st level child elements of calling element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in xmlData.Descendants("b").First()
        select c.Value;
```